# Is the total lift of a quadcopter the sum of the lift from each propeller?

Tags: lift, quadcopter

In this diagram each rotor R1,R2,R3,R4 has an individual lift force of 490 N. All combined, does the total force on this aircraft equal to 1960 N?[image: Model of aircraft]

The aircraft in question is similar to a quadcopter.

Comment: Are R2 and R3 vertically separated, or horizontally?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  490 + 490 + 490 + 490 = 1960.  For practical purposes, the thrusts from individual rotors do not interfere constructively or destructively:  they neither cancel each other out, nor do they help each other.  This case is pretty much the same as multiple propellers mounted on a fixed wing.

The situation becomes more complicated only if some rotors overlap, or are coaxial.